# Enable IntelliSense for Sass in .vue files in VS Code

Tags: sass, vue.js, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to enable IntelliSense for Sass in `.vue` files without associating them with `sass` for it would break off another extensions relying on `.vue` file association?

Comment: Intellisense is working in my vue component with vscode. I've just added the sass plugin and the vue plugin. Which plugins are you using?

Comment: I tried few of them for both vue and sass, currently using `vetur` and `sass-intended`. None of them seem to solve the problem or it's just me can't configure `sass` to work in vue files. Which ones are your extensions?

Comment: Sass 1.4.1 and vue 0.1.5. But i didn't configure anything, it just worked.

Comment: Just to check: you do have the language defined in the `<style>` tag, right? Like: `<style lang="sass">`

Comment: Does intellisense work in .vue file for imported scss as well? In my case it works only for variables declares in the sfc file but not for variables imported from global scss file

Answer (score 1):

To get sass or scss syntax highlighting you need to have the Vetur (octref.vetur) extension installed in VS Code.
I have experienced issues with Vetur that the vue-language-server fails to start, which causes alot of issues with syntax highlighting. I have not found a fix for this except a re-install. Also make sure to run the latest version of VS Code.

In a .vue file, you also need to ensure you use the correct attributes

```
<style lang="sass">
    .my-class
        text-align: center
</style>
```

Or for scss

```
<style lang="scss">
    .my-class {
        text-align: center
    }
</style>
```